# How to select columns and cast column types in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a very large pyspark dataframe in which I need to select a lot of columns (which is why I want to use a for instead of writing each column name). The majority of those columns I need to cast them to DoubleType(), except for one column that I need to keep as a StringType() (column "ID").

When I'm selecting all the columns that I need to cast to DoubleType() I use this code (it works) :

```
df_num2 = df_num1.select([col(c).cast(DoubleType()) for c in num_columns])
```

How can I also select my column "ID" which is a StringType() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List concatenation in python :

```py
df_num2 = df_num1.select(["id"] + [col(c).cast(DoubleType()) for c in num_columns])

# OR

df_num2 = df_num1.select(["id", *(col(c).cast(DoubleType()) for c in num_columns)])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and I get the following error : "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: I checked and I was doing a "remove" in my list num_columns and I made it empty. I corrected this error and it works perfectly now ! Thank you for your time !